# Get information from database without signing out and back in

Tags: php, html, mysql, sql, phpmyadmin

I want to get the updated information from the database when the site is refreshed instead of having to log out and back in.

I get the information form user.php when they login, then they get redirected to memberpage.php. When they refresh memberpage.php, if anything is changed on the database it will be changed on memberpage aswell. So if they logged in with isBanned_reason = 0 and then i change it to 1 on the database, i want that to it to change on the memberpage aswell.

Heres my code : 
user.php

```
<?php
include('password.php');
class User extends Password{

    private $_db;

    function __construct($db){
        parent::__construct();

        $this->_db = $db;
    }

    private function get_user_hash($username){

        try {
            $stmt = $this->_db->prepare('SELECT password, username, memberID, isBanned_reason, Rank FROM members WHERE username = :username AND active="Yes" ');
            $stmt->execute(array('username' => $username));

            return $stmt->fetch();

        } catch(PDOException $e) {
            echo '<p class="bg-danger">'.$e->getMessage().'</p>';
        }
    }

    public function login($username,$password){

        $row = $this->get_user_hash($username);

        if($this->password_verify($password,$row['password']) == 1){

          $_SESSION['loggedin'] = true;
          $_SESSION['username'] = $row['username'];
          $_SESSION['memberID'] = $row['memberID'];
          $_SESSION['Rank'] = $row['Rank'];
          $_SESSION['isBanned_reason'] = $row['isBanned_reason'];


            return true;
        }
    }

    public function logout(){
        session_destroy();
    }

    public function is_logged_in(){
        if(isset($_SESSION['loggedin']) && $_SESSION['loggedin'] == true){
             $_SESSION['Rank'];
             $_SESSION['isBanned_reason'];

                        return true;
        }
    }

}


?>
```

memberpage.php

```
<?php require('includes/config.php'); 



//if not logged in redirect to login page
if(!$user->is_logged_in()){ header('Location: login.php'); } 



//define page title
$title = 'Members Page';

//include header template

?>

<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style/Stylememberpage.css">






<?php if ($_SESSION['isBanned_reason'] == 0) {?>
<body>
   <center>
<p>
<h1 id="Caption1">Secret website title</h1>
<h2 id="Caption2">You are logged in as a staff member</h2>
<ul id="menu">
<li id="items"><a href="index.php">Home</a></li>
<li id="items"><a href="registrer.php">Staff Site</a></li>
<li id="items"><a href="Leaderboards.html">Games</a></l1>
<li id="items"><a href="Contact.html">Leaderboard</a></li>
<li id="items"><a href="logout.php">Log out</a></li>
</body>
</ul>


  </p>
</center>

<?php
}
?>











<?php if ($_SESSION['isBanned_reason'] == 1) {?>
<body>
   <center>
<p>
<h1 id="Banned1">Your account has been locked.</h1>
<h2 id="Banned2">You are banned for until: 12.12.2020 reason : scamming/exploit.</h2>
<ul id="menu">
<li id="items"><a href="index.php">Home</a></li>
<li id="items"><a href="registrer.php">Staff Site</a></li>
<li id="items"><a href="Leaderboards.html">Games</a></l1>
<li id="items"><a href="Contact.html">Leaderboard</a></li>
<li id="items"><a href="logout.php">Log out</a></li>
</body>
</ul>


  </p>
</center>

<?php
}
?>
```

And, if its possible. When i change isBanned_reason on my database, is there any way to "apply" that without the user having to refresh the page? Because i want them to be banned immediately when its changed. How could i do that?

Comment: you can use `jquery ajax` to check information on server or db, without refreshing page on client side

Comment: In your every page or where you want that update, run AJAX call to a PHP file which will always return you the value from DB. Execute that AJAX with timer in every second or every 2 seconds. On success call another ajax to set the session using php.

Comment: @MaheshSinghChouhan ok, thanks.

Comment: @webDev could you post an example answer?

Comment: Try on your own first, thats better way you can learn, first make ajax request to get the value and then set session. See JQuery AJAX examples codes by googling. Do you wanna learn or do you wanna solve your problem??

Answer (score 1):

You can use `jQuery Ajax` function to check on server or database for changed value, also use `setInterval` function to trigger ajax on every `5 seconds`

**Try like this:**

**Jquery Ajax:** (on your pages where you want to trigger the check continuously)

```
setInterval(function(){
  $.ajax({
    url : 'check_db.php', //URL: lets say you have check_db.php in same directory where this file is
    dataType : 'html',
    data : 'post',
    data : {user_id : 'user_id'},
    success : function(response){
      //catch the response here from server
      if (response == 1) {
        window.location.href="logout.php"; //redirecting user to logout
      }
    }
  })
},5000);//Every 5 seconds
```

Also, make sure to load `jquery` library to run `jquery` function like this on top of your page head

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

If you don't want to redirect your page to login and ask re-login then inside your success method of this AJAX call, you need to write another AJAX to set session variable and to hide the banned area. Updating session variable is required because if user refresh the page then your if statement must work properly to check banned session variable.

That's why its better to learn AJAX clearly. [Link](https://www.w3schools.com/jquery/jquery_ref_ajax.asp)

Comment: copy and pasted your code to my memberpage. didnt happend anything.. Should i change the url to my website url and the userid to memberID?

Comment: See updated code, but this will not gonna work untill you learn AJAX. No copy and paste will not work. If you wanna hide or banned some area of a page based on DB. You need to fire two AJAX as well as on second AJAX success you need to hide banned area using JS and CSS. on Refresh the session variable will work.

Comment: You are right buddy, thats why post some link of ajax and related topics like setting session variable using AJAX etc

Comment: i dont have any files called checkdb @webDev

Comment: @UnboxingTutorials thats why my friend, I am telling you, please take a basic AJAX training using google and then you will 100% get this answer working. Just spend a day studying AJAX buddy.

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to use jquery. Here is native javascript that works just as well:

```
var objXhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
objXhttp.open("POST", "http://YourServer.com/CheckForBadUser.php, false);
objXhttp.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
objXhttp.send("nUserID=" + gnUserID);
if (objXhttp.response == 1) {
    ThrowUserOut()
}
```

Do the following steps for this code to work:

1. Create CheckForBadUser.php, which checks to see if a UserID has been marked as bad.
2. Create a global variable named gnUserID in your javascript.
3. Create a javascript function named ThrowUserOut(), which is performed if CheckForBadUser.php returns 1.

   ```
   function ThrowUserOut () {
       document.all.idDivMain.innerHTML = "You've been thrown out!"
   }
   ```
4. At the beginning of your body tag add a div named idDivMain. Remember to close that div right before the end-body.

Comment: Would you please explain how a part of the web page will be banned automatically using your answer?

Comment: I dont understand how that can ban a user on my page? I would need to change alot to make that work?

Comment: See my revised answer, which describes how this code can ban the user from the entire page.